# TCP/IP Implementation General Questions

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, tcp, tcpserver

I've implemented the concepts shown here; http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Simple_TCP/IP_Client_-_Server outside of unity and it works. (though i had to create the TCPIPServerApp from scratch as i could not find the base project anywhere).

I have some general questions on how to use tcp/ip properly however. I've done some research on tcp/ip itself but I'm still a little confused.

It seems like using the method above doesn't guarantee that I'll see the message (res). It just checks on every update to see if there is a different message in res. What if multiple messages are sent and the program lags or something, will i miss the earlier packet(s)? Should i instead do an array so it stores the last X messages?

How do i know the data was received? Do I need to add a message id and build in my own ack into the data?

Should i check to see if the port is in use before setting up a connection?

Sorry for all the questions. This is all new to me but I enjoy this very much!

... Below already answered By Anton, Thanks

It sounds like tcp uses its own packet numbering to ensure the packets end up in the right order on the other side. What if a packet is missed, are the subsequent packets thrown away? Or is this numbering and packet ordering, only for handling data that is broken out into multiple packets?

TCP will automatically break the data into multiple packets if necessary right?

Answer (score 0):

First of all TCP is a connection full protocol so before sending any segments(so data called at the TCP level) a clien and server are connected using a standard TCP handshake
[TCP handshake](http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/tcp/3-way_handshake.shtml)

So after each segment which the client receives it sends back an acknowledgement. So only after that the server sends another segment. Actually they send not one segment, but for the sake of reducing traffic the server can send many segments. However, idea is still the same. Again the TCP is a reliable protocol comparing to UDP where the client never sends back acknowledgements. So an example of UDP is any shooter games where we don't rely on each segment. Everyone definitely saw so called lags in games.

Of course TCP uses ack ids to find out whether the segment was acknowledged or not! But it also needs to know how to build all segments.Remember all data is being sent in portions and after it needs to be built back!

Again how TCP segments data depends on many factors and it's smart enough to find out the best way. For example some networks can have firewalls that block packets that larger than some size. Therefore, TCP segment size can be different.